# Firebase Firestore security rules / Is this safe?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I want to make a security rules that allow reading for all the users know the name of the file.
Is this safe?

path : image / {imageID}

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  // block getting list
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /image {
      allow read : if false
      allow create : if true
    }
    // arrow reading for uses who know the file name
    match /image/{imageID} {
        allow read : if true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific.  "Allow reading for all the users know the name of the file" isn't clear.  I suggest matching specific code to your rules, then checking to see if that code works or doesn't work the way you expect with the rules.  In other words, test it yourself, then post if something doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: So, you are storing the file name as `imageID`? If not, could you share how are validating that the user "knows" the file name?

Comment: yes store as imageID

Comment: ok, but how will you validade that the user knows the `imageID`? Please elaborate on your app's flow of execution, the way you are setting up currently is open for anyone to read.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on console. The rule seems to be safe.